# Select Statement using Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new to using databases,

I have a table ( easy_drinks )

```
+------------+-------------+---------+
| Drink_name |    main     | amount1 |
+------------+-------------+---------+
| Blackthorn | Blackthorn  | 1.5     |
| BlueMoon   | soda        | 1.5     |
| OhMyGosh   | peachnectar | 1       |
+------------+-------------+---------+
```

I have a Query

```
SELECT Drink_name 
FROM easy_drinks 
WHERE main > 'soda'
;
```

It is giving results as **Blakcthorn**

Can you please explain how string comparison occurs between i.e with main and 'soda' ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083781/is-it-safe-to-compare-strings-with-greater-than-and-less-than-in-mysql

Comment: Try `WHERE UPPER(main) > 'soda'` to see the difference. Also try `WHERE 'soda' > 'Soda'`. In short, uppercase "B" is after lower case "s" in the sorting/collating sequence. Thus all values in your database need to be consistent in their capitalization and/or you should user `UPPER()` or `LOWER()` on all values used in comparisons.

Comment: it has to do with character sets and collation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compairs the strings using the underlying values of the `collation` the fields use in a lexiographic order. That means that capitals are "bigger" (before) non capitals.

Note: If both strings use a different collation, one will be converted.

If you do not prefer to distinguish capitals and non capitals use something like

```
SELECT Drink_name 
FROM easy_drinks 
WHERE LOWER(main) > 'soda'
;
```

You can also use the `strcmp` function (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp) ).

```
SELECT Drink_name 
FROM easy_drinks 
WHERE strcmp(LOWER(main),'soda') = 1
;
```