# Is it possible to use a varchar/string for jdbc sql_last_value?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I've already tested the `sql_last_value` with an `integer` and `datetime` type of fields in my `jdbc` plugin within the `logstash` input and it's working perfectly.

I'm just curios, is there any possibility of using a  `varchar/string` type of field, in order to update the `sql_last_value` time to time in case if there aren't any `datetime` or `int` field in my table.

Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show you config file. I am facing similar kind of problem. My logstash is working with sql_last_value as an integer, but it reads old records also. I can see duplicate records in ES. I checked .logstash_jdbc_last_run file, it contains 0. Don't know where I am going wrong. I am using  follwing configuration also                                                    use_column_value => true
            tracking_column => "SEQ_NO"
             record_last_run => true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. As a proof you can look at the [source code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb#L169-L170) for the `jdbc` input plugin.

The declaration of the `tracking_column_type` field  highlights the following:

```
  # Type of tracking column. Currently only "numeric" and "timestamp"
  config :tracking_column_type, :validate => ['numeric', 'timestamp'], :default => 'numeric'
```

This means that this field will only be allowed to contain two values, namely `timestamp` and `numeric`.

Comment: `If tracking column value rather than timestamp, the column whose value is to be tracked
  config :tracking_column, :validate => :string`
from the given link above, could I use just `tracking_column` only in order to compare `string` type column?

Comment: you should try it, no big risk :-)

Comment: Alright, so is there any other way to do the comparison rather than using `> :sql_last_value` since it's a `string` value where you can't check for a greater value ?

Comment: It's definitely ok to [compare strings in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083781/is-it-safe-to-compare-strings-with-greater-than-and-less-than-in-mysql), you should try it out and see if it works for you.